# Java error: non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, class, compilation, super

Here is the given code:

```
class Super {
    protected int n;

    Super(int n){
        this.n=n;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("n="+n);
    }
}

class Sub {
    Sub(int m){
        Super.n=m;
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sub s= new Sub(10);
        s.print();
    }
}
```

I am getting these errors:

> Main.java:19: error: non-static variable n cannot be referenced from a static context
>       Super.n=m;
>       ...........^
>   Main.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
>           s.print();

Can someone please tell me why these errors occur?

Comment: Did you mean for `Sub` to extend `Super`?

Comment: I answered this, but I'm also gonna flag it as a typo unless there's a reason why this isn't just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the Sub class:

```
class Sub {
    Sub(int m){
        Super.n=m; // <- this line of code!
    }
}
```

Super.n is a syntax to access a variable defined in a class scope. In java, we call this kind of variable static variables.

To correct this problem, you have to do the following:

```
// With the extends Super, you are inheriting properies and methods
// from Super class
class Sub extends Super {
    Sub(int m){
        // Now you are calling a constructor from the parent             
        super(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sub` needs to actually inherit `Super`.

`public class Sub extends Super` would make Super's variables accessible from Sub.

Language reference:

[Inheritance in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)